# Лимит на выполнение скрипта

Tags: php, парсер, limit

Доброго времени суток.
В общем возник такой вопрос.

Пишу парсер, изначально выполняю парсинг страниц категории, страниц порядка 4к+, получаю при этом ссылки на товары, которых на каждой странице порядка 10-ти. 
При парсинге категории получаю массив ссылок на товары. Даже не начиная парсить товары упираюсь в лимит хостинга. Как можно обойти этот лимит, может кто-то посоветовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: кушать слона по частям

Comment: Запускать скрипт в консоли, а не через веб сервер, т.к. это консольная задача. Там хоть месяцами будет скрипт выполняться.

Comment: @ilyaplot получается конфиг заданный в php.ini не распространяется на запускаемые в консоли скрипты ?

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev никто не отменял таймаут, заданный в веб сервере. Обычно он не более 30 секунд.

Comment: @rjhdby Вариант, но без "упирания" в лимит я могу спарсить лишь 10 страниц, как-то не очень удобно 4к+ страниц по 10 единиц листать. Опять же если это все сделать в цикле, со все равно в лимит упрусь или же Вы предлагаете это делать Асинхронно ?

Comment: @ilyaplot я о том, что, выполняя скрипт в консоле на него не действуют ограничения данные в php.ini ?

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev для консольного обычно не устанавливают таймаут. К тому же, для консоли свой php.ini

Comment: а что именно лимитируется то?

Answer (score 0):

`упираюсь в лимит хостинга`

А можно ли спросить лимит по каким параметрам? просто есть память и время.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60*60*5); // 5 часов
ini_set('memory_limit', '16000M'); // 16 GB RAM
```

Comment: в лимит по времени выполнения скрипта, который ограничен 30-ю секундами, про **ini_set** знаю, но боюсь что хостинг не одобрит такого решения, пока что пробую через консоль, достиг успеха пока только до 1700 страниц и 4к+, а после Fatal error

Comment: хостинг одобрит. так как вы платите  за него свои дойч марки

Comment: мое мнение что ini_set можно смело использовать. а это у вас хостинг или сервер на линуксе или на чем?